# What does --pre do in gem install rails --pre?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

What does `--pre` do in `gem install rails --pre` ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`--pre` means that it will install the prerelease of the rails gem. For instance when Rails 3 was still in beta, you could still play around with it [by getting the prerelease](http://www.rubyinside.com/how-to-install-rails-3-0-prerelease-beta-2955.html).

You shouldn't run this unless you want to be on edge of a gem (for development or test purposes). I wouldn't recommend putting a website in production with a gem in prerelease as they might not be stable enough yet.

Comment: Yes, but which prerelease? I.e., how can I tell which commit/tag `--pre` will install without installing?

Comment: This will install the latest prerelease that is available. In the case of rails the latest beta or rc version available you can see here: https://rubygems.org/gems/rails

Answer (score 11):

`--pre` flag lets you install a pre-release version of a gem. A pre-release version is any version that has at least one letter in the version number, e.g. '4.1.2.beta1' or '2.3.rc2' and so forth. For example, running:

```
$ gem install rails --pre
```

will install the latest not officially released version of rails (4.1.0.rc1 at the time of writing). If you want to install other than the latest, you may do so by passing the version in the `-v` option, e.g.:

```
$ gem install rails -v 4.1.0.beta1 --pre
```

The command above will install 4.1.0.beta1 version of the rails gem as well. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

If you would like to see what will be installed by a `gem` command, you can use the `--explain` flag.  So, if you wanted to see what version of `rails` would be installed by the `--pre` flag, you can run.

```
gem install rails --pre --explain
```